Whitelist topics and services in rosbridge
I'd like to whitelist topics and services for my rosbridge in the ros2 python launch file. There is one XML launch file here https://github.com/RobotWebTools/rosbridge_suite/blob/humble/rosbridge_server/launch/rosbridge_websocket_launch.xml so I inlcude the XML launch file in the ros2 python launch file. I think we need to specify topics_glob and services_glob to whitelist topics. I tried to pass a list to both services_glob and topics_glob but rosbrdige just concatenates all elements of the list to a single string value when I verified the parameter ros2 param get rosbridge_websocket topics_glob. I then passed a string representation of the list and got the error what():  expected [string_array] got [string]. Any ideas?
import os
import yaml
from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.actions import IncludeLaunchDescription
from launch_xml.launch_description_sources import XMLLaunchDescriptionSource


def generate_launch_description():
    rosbridge_pkg_path = os.path.join(get_package_share_directory("rosbridge_server"),
                                      "launch",
                                      "rosbridge_websocket_launch.xml")
    topics_glob = ["topic_a", "topic_b", "topic_c"]
    services_glob = ["service_a", "service_b", "service_c"]
    rosbridge_launch_arguments = {"port": str(7005),"topics_glob": topics_glob, "services_glob": services_glob}
    rosbridge_include_command = IncludeLaunchDescription(
        XMLLaunchDescriptionSource(rosbridge_pkg_path),
        launch_arguments=rosbridge_launch_arguments.items()
    )

    return LaunchDescription([rosbridge_include_command])

